# Prepend a subtext of a line to the same line

Tags: bash, perl, shell

How to get from the file:

> ```
> This is a line 2
> There is 1 line
> imagine 3 lines
> two times two is 4
> There is no number here
> ```

The following:

> ```
> 2, This is a line 2
> 1, There is 1 line
> 3, imagine 3 lines
> 4, two times two is 4
> ```

So, the prefix is retrieved from the line and it can vary from line to line.
How this can be done in bash and perl?
Roughly like this:

```
s/\d+/$&, $`$&$'/
```

Comment: Take a look at the [perl regex tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) and you should be able to work it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -En 's/.*([0-9]+).*/\1, &/p' filename
```

Comment: What does -E flag do? something related to an Extended regex?
I guess -n suppresses to output those lines where no replacement has happened. Am I right?

Comment: You are right. With `-E` it is possible to omit some backslashes to escape special characters.

Answer (score 3):

Using a perl one-liner

```
perl -ne 'print "$1, $_" if /(\d+)/' filename
```

**Switches**:

- `-n`: Creates a `while(<>){...}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

Comment: I didn't know about -n flag. Nice one!

Answer (score 2):

Using `bash` from the command line:

```
$ while read -r line; do 
    [[ $line =~ [0-9]+ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}, $line"; 
done < file
2, This is a line 2
1, There is 1 line
3, imagine 3 lines
4, two times two is 4
```

Comment: That's to advance for me, I roughly understand the code but don't know the syntax it follows.

Comment: @FiboKowalsky [Here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns#Regular_Expressions-1) is a good reference to get you started.